# Cannot subscribe to webcal feed created with dday.ical

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, outlook, icalendar, outlook-2010

I've been busy trying to create an iCal feed for my website that users can subscribe to. After some initial hassle, I found http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/, which has a feature that does exactly what I want. Downloaded the source, altered it to my liking an needs, done. I can now create a link that downloads a dynamically created iCal file. It can be opened by outlook and everything seems fine.

Except: when I try to create a calendar feed, instead of a download .ics file, outlook tells me that it is not a valid calendar file.

I've created the link to the iCal file as:

```
<a href="webcal://mnelab.3me.tudelft.nl/MyLab/iCalFeed/B928B195-BCC5-4014-AD23-6002B3880A6B/EquipmentBookings">feed</a>
```

(I'm using the RiaLibrary.Web.dll to create the 'fancy' Url.)

When I click the link, my browser asks me if I would like to open the feed with outlook. When I then click 'Lauch application', outlook asks whether I would like to subscribe to the feed. I click yes, and outlook tells that the file 'EquipmentBookings' is not a valid Internet Calendar File.

When I copy paste the address into my browser and replace 'webcal' by 'http', the file is downloaded just fine and opens just as fine in outlook.

The contents of the generated ics file are shown below:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:-//ddaysoftware.com//NONSGML DDay.iCal 1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20120810T120000
DTSTAMP:20120913T222252
DTSTART:20120810T090000
LOCATION:AFM Lab
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Nanosurf easyScan 2 STM
UID:2bed0b80-fb1d-4539-b171-063287dad4a2
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20120814T130000
DTSTAMP:20120913T222252
DTSTART:20120814T090000
LOCATION:AFM Lab
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Nanosurf easyScan 2 STM
UID:15d39ada-f80f-4b95-959d-a60937bb7a85
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I validated them with http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/ and everything seems fine. Which is to be expected, sort of, since the file is opened in outlook without errors. It's just not accepted as a feed.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a really, REALLY lame authentication issue. There was an [Authorize] attribute on the controller class. I have no idea how I could have not seen that. Anyway, it's fixed now.